# Get random images from another gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display 6 random images from a gallery on page id 7 in the sidebar which is on every page of the website.

This is my code but I cannot get the thumbnail link to show!

```
$args = array( 'post_id' => '7', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 6, 'orderby' => 'rand');

        $attachments = get_posts($args);

        if ($attachments) {

            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

                $attachment_id = $attachment();

                print_r($attachment())

                echo '<a href="' .  wp_get_attachment_url() . '"><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ) . '" /></a>';

        }

    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and view your HTML source.

Comment: You're trying to use a variable passed as an executable function. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You are calling `$attachment()` as and id (?!). When you do a `print_r` of `$attachment` in the foreach loop, you can see that they are clearly objects. So you need to get the id from each object by referencing to the needed value with `->` [See here about OOP more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => '7',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

$attachments = get_posts($args);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $attachment_id = $attachment->ID;
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
        if (!empty($image)) {
            $image_url = $image[0];
        }
        echo '<a href="' .  wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) . '"><img src="' . $image_url . '" /></a>';
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also the [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) returns an array that contains

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
[3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available.
```

Since that is an array, I always check if it's not empty (just to be safe).

After querying, always do `wp_reset_postdata();`.

That's it.

**Explanation in a bit more detail**

So what you are doing here is a simple query. You want to get posts, that match some parameters you've set in your `$args` array. You can do a lot with it. [Clicky here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

What that query does is, it returns posts that match your query parameters. And what it returns is an [array of objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). So if you want to access every one of them, you need to [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) through it. And for that there is `foreach` loop.

Foreach will go through every item in your array, and you'll be able to access it as `$attachment` (in your case). You can loop any kind of array. A simple array, a multidimensional array, array containing objects etc.

So, we've said that your query will return a list of [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) (array). Inside your foreach loop `$attachment` is that single object. In general object is a thing that can contain a lot of things. Properties that describe that object, methods (functions in the object) that will make that object do something if you want it to, etc.

Ours object is relatively simple. It contains properties like `ID, post_author,
post_name, post_type, post_title` and more. Basically, all you need to find information about your post.

In our foreach, as mentioned, you are referencing a single object with `$attachment`, and you can get the value of it's various properties by referencing to them like

```
$attachment->ID
```

this will return the value of the `ID` property. If you want to get the post title, you'll reference

```
$attachment->post_title
```

And so on.

So we've assigned that ID to the variable called `$attachment_id`. Now we can freely use it as we wish with various wordpress made functions like `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` for instance.

You need to be aware what you get out of queries and in loops, so it's always good idea, when you're developing stuff, to `print_r()` what you get out.

Also, have in mind that `foreach` will loop through posts one by one. So even if your `print_r($attachment)` returns bunch of posts, it only means that it did that multiple times (well in your case 6 times, since your query returns only 6 posts) and just printed it out. It will be all 'glued' together so you'll think: But wait, this foreach returns tons of stuff. How to get only single stuff?
But just remember that the code inside the `foreach` loop refers to a single instance of your array, and that foreach will go like:

```
item 1 
|
v
do stuff with it... 
|
v
done (output or whatever you are doing in foreach) 
|
v
more items? 
|
v
YES! 
|
v
move to item 2 
|
v
do same stuff with it 
|
v
done 
|
v
more items? 
|
v
YES! 
|
v
move to item 3
.
.
.
|
v
more items? 
|
v
NO :( 
|
v
exit loop
```

And that's how foreach works, so don't be afraid of it :D

I've gone a bit off track, but I hope this helps someone in the future as well :)

Comment: I added it, I just didn't want to loose the first place in the answers ;)

Comment: hahaha! gotcha ;-) Let's see what the OP has to say now. *Cheers*

Comment: This works perfectly, I'm new to PHP so I'm going to go through this code and learn every aspect of it! 

Can you explain whats happening here;  $attachment_id = $attachment->ID;

What is $attachment->ID ?

Comment: Well you are doing a query when you call `get_posts()`. What get that does is return all the posts that match your arguments. The return value is in the form of an array that contains keys, which are themselves [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). The way you extract the information from an object is by referencing to the value of that objects property. So the foreach loop will go through all the posts; `$attachment` is a single object in that loop that contains various properties with values in them. You want the value of the `ID` property of a single object...(1/2)

Comment: ...so what you do is you reference that object's property and you get it's value. That what `$attachment->ID` actually means. It's just one of the properties of the `$attachment` object. (2/2)

Comment: Ok, so I've added an explanation... a bigger one that intended, but whatever :D